# Put a XML file inside a Python script?

Tags: python, xml, string

I'm trying to create a face-detection script using Python's OpenCV using the haar cascade XML file.

My goal is to upload a python file to a website but due to some weird policies, I can only upload the Python file, without the XML...

The question is, is it possible to somehow put the XML file inside the Python script, say, convert it to a String or something and then generate an XML from that String?

Comment: "I can only upload the Python file, without the XML". Does that mean you can only upload `.py` extension files?

Comment: Well technically I need to convert the .py to .exe, and I don't have write permissions. The Pyinstaller automatically unpacks the XML to a Temp folder which is not allowed. That is why I have to keep everything inside a python file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>Yes, you can embed XML in a string literal in Python.</b>
</a>"""
```

Comment: How would you convert it back to XML?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it back to XML?"   It is XML now.  Are you asking how to write this XML string to a file, or how to parse/manipulate this XML via an XML library?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was testing things. The function cv2.CascadeClassifier is apparently expecting a file path, so I'm not sure it'll work even like this.

Comment: After your program is installed and while it is running, are you then allowed to write an XML file to the filesystem prior to creating `cv2.cv2.CascadeClassifier`?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the file must be in read-only mode which makes things difficult.

Comment: If you feel I've answered your original question about how to embed an XML file in a Python script, please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer.   It seems that you have another question (the X in an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?).  Perhaps you should post again asking directly how `cv2.CascadeClassifier` could be used without access to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Not answer to title but answer of your description question.
Haar cascade doesn't support non-file XML strings. Also, if you try to put an XML file to a website and give a link to an XML file with `cv2.CascadeClassifier()`, it will give an error.
But you can use the request module on python to achieve what you want.
It gets XML from the website, then puts it into a file

```py
def function(self, image):
        # download XML from server
        link = LINK_TO_XML
        r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
        open('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml', 'wb').write(r.content)
        # end of download      
        
        haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Answer (score -2):

First, copy the contents of the XML file into the python file and assign the whole thing to a string.  Then use XML library to create a tree type data structure named root which contains the contents of the XML file.  This tree is traversable and you can do what you like with it in your program:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
    root = ET.fromstring(XML_file_example_as_string).
```

To generate XML from the string you can use ElementTree.write() like this:

```
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('example.xml')
```